# Spring Roo: Unable to perform reverse engineer in SqlServer: connection reset

Tags: sql-server, spring, jpa, roo

I'm trying to reverse engineer a sqlserver database, but unfortunately I got stuck when executing the following command:

```
database introspect --schema dbo
```

The result after a few seconds:

> Connection reset

I have successfully configured the database properties (jpa setup) and installed the jtds driver. 
I can connect to the database with the same credentials using RazorSQL.

Any idea or help is welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: The user hadn't enough permissions and we moved him from mixed to sql mode.